# Google chart, visulization controlle values

Tags: google-visualization

I need to alter value when user select the value from google chart dropdown,

please check the code, I need when user select subject value, then I can alert the message or selected value,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>
    Google Visualization API Sample
  </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
      packages: ['controls']
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function drawVisualization() {
      // Prepare the data
      var jsonData = '{"cols":[{"label":"Subject","type":"string"},{"label":"pete","type":"number"},{"label":"john","type":"number"},{"label":"carl","type":"number"},{"label":"andrea","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"coolness"},{"v":4.4},{"v":4.3},{"v":3.1},{"v":4.3}]},{"c":[{"v":"sexyness"},{"v":4.2},{"v":3.8},{"v":3.6},{"v":4.8}]},{"c":[{"v":"toughness"},{"v":3.1},{"v":2.7},{"v":2.4},{"v":2.9}]},{"c":[{"v":"chillnes"},{"v":4.4},{"v":4.4},{"v":4.2},{"v":4.5}]},{"c":[{"v":"madness"},{"v":4.6},{"v":4.6},{"v":4},{"v":4.6}]},{"c":[{"v":"lochness"},{"v":3.9},{"v":3.7},{"v":2.9},{"v":3.9}]},{"c":[{"v":"extraness"},{"v":4.6},{"v":4.3},{"v":3.6},{"v":4.3}]}]}';

      console.log(typeof(responseText));
      console.log(jsonData);

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSON.parse(jsonData));




      var compPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'control2',
        'options': {
          'filterColumnLabel': 'Subject',
          'ui': {
            'labelStacking': 'vertical',
            'allowTyping': false,
            'allowMultiple': true
          }
        }
      });
      // Define a chart
      var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
        'containerId': 'chart1',
        'options': {
          'title': 'Competenties',
          'width': '100%',
          'height': 300,
          'vAxis': {
            viewWindow: {
              max: 5,
              min: 0
            },
            gridlines: {
              color: '#CCC',
              count: 6
            }
          },
          bar: {
            groupWidth: '80%'
          },
          colors: ["#FFC000", "#00b0f0", "#ff0000", "#92d050"]

        }
      });

      // Define a table
      var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Table',
        'containerId': 'chart2',
        'options': {
          'width': '400px'
        }
      });

      // Create a dashboard
      var drawChart = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).bind([compPicker], [chart, table]);;
      drawChart.draw(data);


    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
  </script>
</head>

<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
  <div id="dashboard">

    <table>
      <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
        <td>
          <div id="control1"></div>
          <div id="control2"></div>
          <div id="control3"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="float: left;" id="chart1"></div>
          <div style="float: left;" id="chart2"></div>
          <div style="float: left;" id="chart3"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[JS fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/fcqeA/71/)

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `'statechange'` event listener to determine when values are selected...

Then `compPicker.getState().selectedValues` to get the selected values in an array...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart', 'table']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  var jsonData = '{"cols":[{"label":"Subject","type":"string"},{"label":"pete","type":"number"},{"label":"john","type":"number"},{"label":"carl","type":"number"},{"label":"andrea","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"coolness"},{"v":4.4},{"v":4.3},{"v":3.1},{"v":4.3}]},{"c":[{"v":"sexyness"},{"v":4.2},{"v":3.8},{"v":3.6},{"v":4.8}]},{"c":[{"v":"toughness"},{"v":3.1},{"v":2.7},{"v":2.4},{"v":2.9}]},{"c":[{"v":"chillnes"},{"v":4.4},{"v":4.4},{"v":4.2},{"v":4.5}]},{"c":[{"v":"madness"},{"v":4.6},{"v":4.6},{"v":4},{"v":4.6}]},{"c":[{"v":"lochness"},{"v":3.9},{"v":3.7},{"v":2.9},{"v":3.9}]},{"c":[{"v":"extraness"},{"v":4.6},{"v":4.3},{"v":3.6},{"v":4.3}]}]}';
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSON.parse(jsonData));

  var compPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'control2',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Subject',
      'ui': {
      'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': true
      }
    }
  });

  // listen for 'statechange' event on ControlWrapper
  google.visualization.events.addListener(compPicker, 'statechange', function () {
    // log selected values array
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += JSON.stringify(compPicker.getState().selectedValues) + '<br/>';
  });


  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
    'containerId': 'chart1',
    'options': {'title':'Competenties',
      'width':'100%',
      'height':300,
      'vAxis': {
      viewWindow: {max:5,min:0},
        gridlines: {color:'#CCC', count: 6}
      },
      bar: { groupWidth: '80%' },
      colors: ["#FFC000","#00b0f0","#ff0000","#92d050"]
    }
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Table',
    'containerId': 'chart2',
    'options': {
      'width': '400px'
    }
  });

  var drawChart = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
  drawChart.bind([compPicker], [chart, table]);
  drawChart.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
  <table>
    <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
      <td>
        <div id="control1"></div>
        <div id="control2"></div>
        <div id="control3"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="float: left;" id="chart1"></div>
        <div style="float: left;" id="chart2"></div>
        <div style="float: left;" id="chart3"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="message"></div>
```